# Intended infinite recursion, no-return functions

Tags: c++, c, theory

Infinite recursion is most often not desired, and when it happens it usually causes a stack overflow or segfaults.

But for theory's sake, and plain curiosity, I've been thinking if it'd be possible to create actual infinite recursion, intentionally.

Working in C++ and C where the stack, usually, grows for each function call, and each function returns and pops the part of the stack it handled.

Here's the thought. Would it be possible to force a function to clear out it's own stack space and then call another function so that the new function effectively replaces the first function, without the first function needing to return and then fire again via a loop.

I'm not only thinking about plain loops as a possible use for this, if there would be any. Loops usually do a good job at what they do. But what if you were to use it for sending signals through a node network, that carry on indefinitely in their own process threads until they reach a certain condition. It *might* be a tool that could be used for some problems.

Remember, I'm not really asking if it's practical, only if it's possible to do. For science!

Comment: Your forth paragraph does not describe recursion.

Comment: I described one possible use, and I'm asking about recursion separately. What's the point with your statement?

Comment: You may want to read about http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style (and its use relies on a proper tail calls optimisation).

Comment: @Patrick87: I'm not sure I saw your example, and I can't find it now. Did you remove it?

Comment: @Zoomulator: Yeah, turns out I made a mistake. Sorry... please ignore.

Answer (score 15):

> Would it be possible to force a function to clear out it's own stack
>   space and then call another function so that the new function
>   effectively replaces the first function

This is used for [tail-call-optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310974/what-is-tail-call-optimization), so yes, it is possible and used in practice. In languages like C++ this a nice feature, because sometimes algorithms are simpler to express using recursion, but more efficiently implemented using a loop. The transformation can in some cases be done automatically by the compiler.

Comment: This is not what OP asked: tail-call optimization is about replacing recursion with a loop, whereas he's talking about wiping out the stack of the frames which were allocated for the function invocation.

Comment: @akappa: No, tail call optimisation is exactly what the OP describes. If it's a recursive call to the current function, then you end up with a loop as you describe; a tail call to another function can be implemented by wiping the current stack frame and branching to the other function.

Comment: @akappa: Are you sure that tail-call optimization always produces a loop? What if the a functions calls different other functions based on a condition? This is not easily replaced by a loop, but could be optimized away.

Comment: @akappa, how would you replace with a loop an indirect tail call, like in `return (*someptr)(args...)`?

Comment: Umh, I've seen tail-call optimization in the context of quicksort, and it was an optimization done manually in the source code. It appears that you're right and my idea of "tail-recursion" is wrong.

Comment: I would prefer a manual optimization over a compiler side one, since different compilers would most likely handle it differently, or am I wrong?

Comment: @Zoomulator: Compilers are usually better than humans at optimization.

Comment: @Zoomulator, there are languages which specifications explicitly requires that compiler do an optimisation. There are VMs (e.g., .NET) which provide an explicit tail call annotation. It is not possible at all to do it manually for a generic case.

Comment: @Björn Pollex: I'm wondering mainly if there's a way of guaranteeing it across implementations rather than having it more optimized on a few compilers.

Answer (score 5):

There is a technique called trampolining that is used to implement [continuation-passing style](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Continuation-passing_style) programming without the use of tail-call optimization. If you consider any language without support for TCO, such as JavaScript, and research solutions for CPS in that language, then it is likely that the solution involves trampolining.

Essentially, with trampolining there is a function called a trampoline which iteratively calls thunk-returning functions.

I know that you said "without the first function needing to return and then fire again via a loop"—that's what trampolining is—but considering that this is C++, leaving scopes by, for example, returning is central to the core design of C++'s automatic resource management via destructors (see: RAII). You could alternatively use C's `setjmp()`/`longjmp()` functions to wipe out stack, but then you would need to be very careful in making sure that all resources are released properly.

Comment: You'd need an inline assembly to do trampolining efficiently in C++. And yet, it is significantly less efficient than a simple rewind-the-stack-and-jump sequence.

Answer (score 2):

This does remind me of an optimisation that can be done in assembler code. Say you have this:

```
  call FuncA
  call FuncB
```

you can replace it with:

```
  push ReturnAddress
  push FuncB
  jmp FuncA
ReturnAddress:
```

This causes the `ret` at the end of `FuncA` to jump to `FuncB` directly rather than back to the caller and then onto `FuncB`. Not really possible in higher level languages.

There's also this:

```
 call FuncA
 ret
```

which can be changed to:

```
 jmp FuncA
```

Comment: I use your second trick all the time. But what's the point of your first construct?

Comment: @TonyK: The first one replaces four jumps (call-ret-call-ret) with three (jmp-ret-ret). And it's not limited to two calls, you can daisy chain any number of calls.

Comment: In fact it replaces call-ret-call-ret with push-push-jmp-ret-ret. Is that ever an improvement?

Comment: Well, the call-ret-call-ret is a push-jump-ret-push-jump-ret, so it is better plus you only do one memory load for the code, i.e. the code at the call-call is not reloaded between calls - there's three code loads instead of four. Less memory access the better.

Comment: I'm quite unfamiliar with how to implement assembly code. Would there be a reasonable way of making this as an inline wrapper in C/C++ to make a function act this way? Thanks for the answer nonetheless!

Comment: @Zoomulator: I was going to say there's no way to do this, but, and this is a very technical but, you could have [naked functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d12973a.aspx) (in DevStudio anyway, other compilers will differ).

Comment: @TonyK: Push-push-jmp-ret-ret may be inferior to call-ret-call-ret, but it can also replace call-ret-call-ret-jmp since pushed "return" address can be anywhere.  A more significant aspect of ppjrr is that the pushed addresses may be the results of computations, and need not exist in any register at the time the "computed jump is taken.